# Detecting / finishing Activity on Home button press in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, onkeydown, android-homebutton

I have a `service,` and when tapped a button, My Activity, fragment opens.
This is an Editor screen activity.

I have another activity on top of it, A `chooser Activity.`

When the user presses the `Home` button from the `Editor Activity,` the activity lifecycle goes to the `onStop.`

I am updating the parent service in the `onDestroy` of the `Editor Activity.`

When the user presses the back button, it calls `onDestroy` and updates the parent service layout.

However, when the `Home` button is pressed, the activity calls the `onStop,` and the service is not updated.

I need to finish the activity when the `Home` button is pressed.

I cannot use the `onUserLeaveHint()` as I have the `chooser Activity` on top of the `Editor Activity.`

I cannot destroy the Activity in `onStop` as well, because of the `chooser Activity.`

I have also tried using the `onKeyDown,` but didn't get detected on pressing the `Home` button.

Also tried `clearTaskOnLaunch` and `launchMode = singleInstance` as well.

Answer (score 2):

In Android, when the user presses the "Home" button, the current activity goes into the background, and the user returns to the device's home screen. By default, the activity is not finished or destroyed when the "Home" button is pressed. Instead, it enters the "paused" state, and its lifecycle methods, such as onPause() and onStop(), are called.

However, if you want to finish the activity explicitly when the "Home" button is pressed, you can override the onUserLeaveHint() method in your activity. This method is called when the user navigates away from your activity, which includes cases like pressing the "Home" button.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class YourActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Your activity setup and initialization here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
        super.onUserLeaveHint();
        // Finish the activity when the Home button is pressed
        finish();
    }
}
```

In this example, when the user presses the "Home" button, the onUserLeaveHint() method is called, and we override it to call finish(), which will destroy the current activity and remove it from the backstack.

Comment: But as I have mentioned above onUserLeaveHint() also finishes my Activity when it goes to the chooser screen. That is I have an activity on top of it

Comment: then you should check there hasFocus using onWindowsFocus() override method.